# Django Admin app's contents are not being displayed

Tags: python, django

For some reason, The contents of the database containing the `list of all the Projects` is not being displayed on my `Projects/Issues page` for some reason.

I recently added a feature to my software making it such a way that everytime I click on save in the `Issues page`, an email is sent to the Admin and the Person who is concerned. Ever since I added that feature, my Website stopped displaying the contents but it displays the Number of contents in my List.

**UPDATE**
the 1st entry on the `Project page` doesn't show up. the title of the table doesn't show up either. But when I add the 2nd entry, the 2nd entry shows up, but the 1st doesn't. Im using SQLite. Ill be using MySQL for production.
In my `Issues/Bugs table` None of my entries show up, neither does the title of the table show up. Which means, I cant delete the entries or make any changes to the entires I have made so far. 
Could someone help me out?
**Here's my Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
       ('Technician', 'Technician'),
       ('Tester', 'Tester')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
   )
   Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Project_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Admin_Name_users+')
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_1_users+')
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_1_users+')
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_3_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Tester_1_users+')
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project_Name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "List Of Projects"

class Bug(models.Model):

   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
       ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Tested', 'tested'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Bug', 'Bug'),
       ('Issue', 'Issue'),
       ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
       ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   Project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Issue_Title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Situation_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Basic_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Detailed_Description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
   Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Assigned_to_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reporters_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Deadline_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents_By_Reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Project_Managers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Project_Manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Technicians_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Testers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return '{} ({})  [{}]'.format(self.Project, self.Situation_Type, self.Status, self.Issue_Title)


   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
       if self.id:
           user=self.Assigned_to
           self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID=user.email
       send_mail(self.Admin_Mail_ID, ass=self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID)
       super(Bug, self).save()

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Projects Tasks/Issues"




def send_mail(admin,ass):
    email=EmailMessage('Changes made to Task','Changes have been made to one of your Task reports and we hereby request you to have a look at it at the earliest.', to=[admin,ass])
    email.send()
```

**Here's my Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bug, Project
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
admin.site.register(LogEntry)


# Register your models here.


class BugDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('Project', 'Status', 'Basic_Description', 'Assigned_to', 'Created', 'Updated')
       list_filter = ('Status', 'Assigned_to', 'Project')
       search_fields = ('Reporters_Mail_ID', 'Reported_by', 'Basic_Description',)



admin.site.register(Bug, BugDisplay)


# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('Project_Name','Admin_Name', 'Project_Manager_1', 'Status_of_the_project')
       list_filter = ('Admin_Name', 'Project_Manager_1', 'Status_of_the_project')
       search_fields = ('Project_Name', 'Project_Description', 'Admin_Name', 'Admin_Mail_ID', 'Project_Manager_1 '
                        'Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID', 'Project_Manager_2 ', 'Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID',
                        'Technician_1',
                        'Technician_1_Mail_ID', 'Technician_2', 'Technician_2_Mail_ID', 'Technician_3',
                        'Technician_3_Mail_ID', 'Tester_1', 'Tester_1_Mail_ID', 'Additional_User_1', 'Additional_User_1_Type',
                        'Additional_User_1_Mail_ID', 'Additional_User_2', 'Additional_User_2_Type', 'Additional_User_2_Mail_ID',
                        'Additional_User_3', 'Additional_User_3_Type', 'Additional_User_3_Mail_ID', 'Status_of_the_project', 'Created',
                        'Finish_Date', 'Supporting_Documents')
```

**Here's my Settings.py**

```
Django settings for Buggie project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i^7y!lxfd%h^6#czbx*3-80jsjt_k19#zx!_b(9#7##t129+bg'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')






# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Issues.apps.IssuesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Buggie.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Buggie.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 240*60
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

My Views.py doesn't have any code in it.

Comment: Why so denormalized?

Comment: Have you tried a minimal working example with just admin.site.register(Project) and admin.site.register(Bug)?